# Swift swiping menu

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have to make an iOS app which looks pretty much like [this one](https://dribbble.com/shots/2663131-Movies), but I'm having some serious issues with the menu.

Right now I am using iCarousel, which works fine but the widths of the menu titles  are constant. So if I have large titles and I put a large amount of spacing there can be a lot of space between small titles. On the other hand, if I put a small amount of spacing, some titles are cut.

Do you have any idea how I can have dynamic widths for my menu? Maybe by using something other than iCarousel, or even something other than Swift (React native for example) if I have to.

Comment: What kind of menu you using is it a another collectionView

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
 
Right now I'm using two carousels, one for the movies and one for the menu.

Do you think if I use a UICollectionView instead, I can have my menu to act like the one in the video?

Horizontal scrolling is easy, dynamic widths depending on the label size seems like something possible to do.
But is it possible when scrolling to put the nearest cell to the middle of the screen and get the indexpath of the cell?
Or disable scrolling and add a cell by cell scrolling action.

Again thank you.

Comment: try collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath method . This method will give you a functionality like when you press  any  collectionViewCell it will automatically move to center,left or right....you need to play with UIAnimation as well to get a smooth animation...

Comment: try below code to achieve the animation one showed in the video. put this code inside your collectionViewDidSelect .....                                     if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row > 0 {
                collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).item, section: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally) 
            }    hope this helps.....

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know!